# android phone screen orientation related issue?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

friends,

i am facing an issue related to android phone screen orientation

If i change the orientation of the phone, then it loses the context, if i am in middle of filling a simple form. So, the phone is vertical, I am using soft keyboard, I make it horizontal, so that I can use the  keyboard easily again or something else, and kaboom, everything I have entered so far is lost.

any one guide me what is the solution to keep data and state same after changing orientation?

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: hmm...could you past some more relevant code? Konstantin is right in saying that the activity is re-created, but I couldn't reproduce the problem on a simple form with input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because activity is actually re-created on orientation change. You have to save your state before the change and then restore it. Override onSaveInstanceState to save your data to bundle. The data is then accessible at onCreate (withing the bundle again).

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      outState.putSerializable("Key", "Some data"); //put some data
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```